# AngularJS - Call Controller function from Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**HTML**

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#dateControls')).append($compile("<search-date></search-date>")($scope));
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('searchDate', function ($compile, $rootScope,$timeout) {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var template =  '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dateSearch() id="playbackSearch" search-date">Search</button>';

            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

    };
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        replace: true,
        link: linker
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.dateSearch = function(){

    scope.userId = 1;
    myModuleService.getData(userId) //call service
    then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    }).catch(function (error) {
        throw error;
    });
};
```

How do I call function `dateSearch()` defined in my controller ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a controller in directive itself.Since your `myModuleService` is external service

like

```
controller:function($scope,myModuleService)
{

$scope.dateSearch = function(){

    scope.userId = 1;
    myModuleService.getData(userId) //call service
    then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    }).catch(function (error) {
        throw error;
    });
};

}
```

or in your style

```
var controll:function($scope,myModuleService)
    {

    $scope.dateSearch = function(){

        scope.userId = 1;
        myModuleService.getData(userId) //call service
        then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        }).catch(function (error) {
            throw error;
        });
    };

    }
 return {
        restrict: "EA",
        replace: true,
        link: linker,
        controller:controll
    };
```